# MVVM object fire property changed event when a field is changed

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

So I have an MVVM binding setup for an object.  The object is of a class like the following:

```
public class SomeClass
{
  public int Field1 {get; set:}
  public List<MyClass> CollectionOfObjects {get; set;}
  public string Description {get; set;}
}
```

My MVVM class implements INotifyPropertyChanged ...

```
private SomeClass _viewableObject;
public SomeClass ViewableObject
{
    get
     {
       return _viewableObject;
     }
    set
     {
        _viewableObject = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("ViewableObject");
     }


}
```

This works great in the case where I'm defining a new object.  For instance:

```
 ViewableObject = new SomeClass();
```

But I'm binding UI components to fields of `SomeClass`.  `Field1` and `Description`  get pushed to a textboxes and say `CollectionOfObjects` gets pushed to a `DataGrid`.

```
<Datagrid .... ItemsSource = "{Binding ViewableObject.CollectionOfObjects}" ></DataGrid>
```

So in the event that I update just `ViewableObject.CollectionOfObjects` and not the whole `ViewableObject` how can I get the UI to update to reflect the modification?  Is there a cleaner way to do that rather than splitting up each field of `SomeClass` in the MVVM?

Comment: (A) Make `CollectionOfObjects` an *ObservableCollection*... (B) Implement *INotifyPropertyChanged* for `SomeClass`, otherwise bindings using properties of *SomeClass* won't update if those properties change...

Comment: @elgonz Yeah, that's the direction I'm probably going to go if there is no other way.

Comment: everytime you modify/update the `CollectionOfObjects`, also try calling `OnPropertyChanged("ViewableObject");`, not sure if it works but worth trying.

Comment: @KingKing I was thinking (dreamed it last night) about just adding a refresh event to the MVVM class, When called it updates all properties in the MVVM or more specifically, the components that are not Value Types.  I haven't been able to try it yet.

Comment: not an event but a simple refresh method.

Comment: @elgonzo your comment is really the answer here. +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own collection that implements [INotifyCollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx), but you'll find it's easier to just use an [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx) which does that already.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options here. The simplest of which is to convert `CollectionOfObjects` from a `List<MyClass>` to an `ObservableCollection<MyClass>` - as has already been mentioned.

Be aware, however, that this will only give the UI notification when new items are added to the `ObservableCollection`, or existing items are removed.

If you change the entire reference that `CollectionOfObjects` points to, then using an `ObservableCollection` is of no use. Instead, you will need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on `SomeClass` and raise `PropertyChanged` events when each property value is set.

The resulting `SomeClass` would be look like this:

```
public class SomeClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public SomeClass()
    {
        CollectionOfObjects = new ObservableCollection<MyClass>();
    }

    public int Field1 
    {
        get 
        {
            return _field1;
        }
        set
        {
            if(_field1 != value)
            {

                _field1 = value;
                PropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Field1"));
            }
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<MyClass> CollectionOfObjects 
    {
        get 
        {
            return _collectionOfObjects;
        }
        set
        {
            if(_collectionOfObjects != value)
            {

                _collectionOfObjects = value;
                PropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("CollectionOfObjects"));
            }
        }
    }

    public string Description
    {
        get 
        {
            return _description;
        }
        set
        {
            if(_description != value)
            {

                _description = value;
                PropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Description"));
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate {}

    private int _field1;
    private ObservableCollection<MyClass> _collectionOfObjects;
    private string _description;
}
```

Note that this is not strictly speaking a Model object any more. It's dependence on `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `ObservableCollection` make it a ViewModel. But, you already have one of those...

The choice is whether you can tolerate 'polluting' your model class to the point that it becomes a ViewModel. This is absolutely fine for some scenarios. In other cases, it is preferential to strictly separate the concerns of Model and ViewModel. At this point, you need introduce a mapper which is able to convert from Model to ViewModel - probably vice-versa, too. Perhaps the Model is a database record, or something else entirely. It might need to depend on other libraries, inherit from some layer-specific base class, or contain lots of domain logic.

A further benefit of strictly separating Model and ViewModel is that the two can vary independently. The Model might contain some properties that the UI - and therefore the ViewModel - need not contain. Or, the ViewModel might aggregate some properties into an average, or a total, etc. ViewModels should typically have properties that map to the user interface, whereas Models might not.

One final note. By introducing a mapper and properly separating Model and ViewModel, what would you call the existing ViewModel class that you have? I tend to refer to this as a Controller. The pattern, then, becomes M-V-C-VM: Model-View-Controller-ViewModel. The Controller remains the `DataContext` of a UI element but exposes a `ViewModel` property. The Controller should first load Model data (possibly via a repository interface) then ask a mapper to convert the Model to an MVVM-specific ViewModel.

If you're using Dependency Injection, then Controllers would accept service interfaces as constructor parameters but ViewModels would not have services as constructor parameters: they would be fairly dumb bags of data.

I'll reiterate that this can be overkill, but it is also sometimes the best option available.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everyone for the suggestions.  The solution that I used is as follows:

```
public class SomeClass : ObservableCollection<Elements>
{
  private int _field1;

  public int Field1 
   {
    get
     {
      return _field1;
     }
    set
     {
      _field1 = value;
      OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
     }
   }

  private string _description;
  public string Description 
   {
    get
     {
      return _description;
     }
    set
     {
      _description= value;
      OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
     }
   }

  // remove this since the class is now the collection.
  // public List<MyClass> CollectionOfObjects {get; set;}
}
```

Now `SomeClass` extends [`ObservableCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx) therefore has a `CollectionChangedEvent`

So in my MVVM class I added the following:

**A handler**

```
    private void CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.OnPropertyChanged("ViewableObject");

    }
```

**Assign the handler to the event**

```
private SomeClass _viewableObject;
public SomeClass ViewableObject
{
     get
     {
      return _viewableObject;
     }
     set
     {
      _viewableObject = value;

      if(value != null)
         _viewableObject.CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(CollectionChanged)

      OnPropertyChanged("ViewableObject");
     }


}
```

Considering the whole problem to start out with was that the only time the code from the MVVM would fire is when a new assignment happened the event handler is only called when needed.  I think this is a simple way to approach it.